# Extract words within curly quotes but keep it when used as apostrophe

Tags: bash, sed, utf-8, grep

I have a **UTF-8 file** which has curly quotes `‘Awaara’` like these and in some places  curly quotes are used such as `don’t` and `don't'` . The issue arises when trying to convert these curly quotes to single quotes. After converting to single quotes, I am unable to extract the single quotes words `'Awaara'` without removing all single quotes used as `don't , I'm`.

**GOAL: Convert curly--> single, remove single quotes yet keep apostrophied single quotes.**

Here's the code I have written which convert yet fails to remove words within single quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash



cat $1 | sed -e "s/\’/'/g" -e  "s/\‘/'/g" | sed -e "s/^'/ /g" -e "s/'$/ /g" | sed "s/\…/ /g" | tr '>' ' ' | tr '?' ' ' | tr ',' ' ' | tr ';' ' ' | tr '.' ' ' | tr '!' ' ' | tr '′' ' ' | tr ':' ' ' | sed -e "s/\[/ /g" -e "s/\]/ /g" -e 's/(/ /g' -e "s/)/ /g" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | uniq | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' >our_vocab.txt
```

The output is:

```
'AWAARA ---> Should be AWAARA
25
50
70
800
A
AD
AI
AMITABH
AND
ANYWAY
ARE
BACHCHAN
BECAUSE
BUT
C++
CAN
CHECK
COMPUTER
DEVAKI
DIFFICULT
.
.
. 
HOON'   --> Should be HOON
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample *input* too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E -e "s/([[:alpha:]]['’][[:alpha:]])|['‘’]/\\1/g" \
  -e 's/[][()>?,;.!:]|′|…/ /g' "$1" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | \
  tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' > our_vocab.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EGHb89).

I merged several `tr` commands into a single (second) `sed` command, and the `([[:alpha:]]['’][[:alpha:]])|['‘’]` regex removes all `'‘’` apostrophes other than those in between letters.